# Birth certificate in Algeria

Tags: birth-records, spain

I am trying to get the birth certificates of two people who were born in 1920 in Algeria in "Sidi - Biraber" and in "Sebdon Oran".

By the names and surnames I believe the individuals were Spanish but born in Algeria.

And I can't find the towns, could it be that they changed their name?

In my father's birth certificates it says that his mother and grandmother were born in those two cities as I have written them.

Comment: Javi, I've done a Google translate of your original question as we require all questions and answers to be in English (a  translation is allowed, but we can't cater for non-English questions or answers without any English equivalent.)

Comment: ¡Hola Javi! ¿Cuál es el origen de la información que tienes sobre los nombres de las localidades "Sidi - Biraber" y "Sebdon Oran"? ¿Es esto de una acta de defunción o de un censo u otro documento? / Hi Javi, what is the origin of the information that you have about the names of the towns "Sidi - Biraber" and "Sebdon Oran"? Is this from a death certificate or a census or another document?

Comment: Based on https://www.cia.gov/library/readingroom/docs/CIA-RDP01-00707R000100150010-1.pdf and other internet articles, I wonder if Sebdon might be Sebdou? 
Basado en https://www.cia.gov/library/readingroom/docs/CIA-RDP01-00707R000100150010-1.pdf y otros artículos de Internet, me pregunto si Sebdon podría ser Sebdou.

Comment: Sebdon is mentioned in https://www.econlib.org/book-chapters/chapter-v-1-entry-35-algeria/

Comment: En las partidas de nacimiento de mi padre pone que su madre y abuela nacieron en esas dos ciudades tal cual las he escrito. (Y perdona por lo del ingles...)

Answer (score 3):

Algeria at the time was part of France. Algerian archives were only partially (about 60-70%) brought back to France when Algeria gained their independence in the 1960s. Whichever registers were brought back have been digitalized and put online for free on the [ANOM](http://anom.archivesnationales.culture.gouv.fr/caomec2/recherche.php?territoire=ALGERIE) website. Records prior to 1904 have been indexed, and records prior to 1918 are online.

Births from 1920 are a little too recent to be online, but they might be available from the [Service Central d'Etat-Civil](https://pastel.diplomatie.gouv.fr/dali/index2.html). You'll need to be more precise in your demand.

I agree with other people that Sebdon Oran is most likely [Sebdou](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sebdou) and Sidi - Biraber is most likely [Sidi bel Abbès](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidi_Bel_Abb%C3%A8s).

Answer (score -1):

Based on https://www.britannica.com/place/Sidi-Bel-Abbes and other internet articles, Sidi - Biraber might be Sidi Bel Abbès:

"Sidi Bel Abbès town, northwestern Algeria, on the Wadi Mekerra in the Tell Atlas Mountains".

Sidi - Biraber could be a corruption of Sidi Bel Abbès.

Comment: Please post the relevant part of that article here.  Answers consisting only of links are not very helpful and are likely to be deleted.